# UITableView does not change it size correctly on device orientation change

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, device-orientation

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new to iOS dev,

I've UIWebView and UITableView on my iPad view.
In `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` I resize them for nice look like this.

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {    
        if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
            CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
            self.mTextView.frame = f;
            f = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
            self.mTableView.frame = f;
        }
        if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {     
            CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height);
            self.mTextView.frame = f;
            f = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, 0, self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height);
            self.mTableView.frame = f;        
        }   
        return YES;
    }
```

Now the question:
For the first load the table view is drawn with correct sizes but when I switch to portrait mode then back to landscape mode the UITableView becomes wider than specified by frame. So why this happens and how to fix this ?

PS. I've tried also to set the frames for all cells in the same method didn't help.

PSS. This happens only on device, on simulator UITableView is displayed correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` only returns a boolean value indicating whether the view controller supports the specified orientation, you should not do any UI transformation in this method, instead do everything in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{    
    if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
        self.mTextView.frame = f;
        f = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
        self.mTableView.frame = f;
    }
    if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {     
        CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height);
        self.mTextView.frame = f;
        f = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, 0, self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height);
        self.mTableView.frame = f;        
    }
}
```

[Have a look at the documentation for UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a), it's well explained.

Comment: Thanks ! Really dummy question !

Answer (score 2):

iOS calls this function just one time! For doing this work nice as you expect, you must add this line into the `(void)viewDidLoad` function:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

And making `(void)orientationChanged:(id)object` function:

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(id)object{
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation;

    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)){
        // some works
    }else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)){
        // another works
    }
}
```

I hope it be useful for you!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the size of UITableView in both portrait and landscape modes. UITableView change size automatically in a ratio with respect to previous orientation mode . So you can fix desired size for both modes.

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `autoResizing` property of the views.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is you can make 2 diffrent view for the portrait and landscape mode so whenever mode changes you can easily change the view.
Like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        self.view = self.portraitView;
    else 
        self.view = self.landscapeView;
    [tblScore reloadData];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you use `AutoResizing` for this no need to do coding for frame..
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html